# How to set DataSource Form LinkType property in Delayed or Passive by code?

Tags: forms, datasource, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have to set the form `DataSource` LinkType Property in to Delayed or Passive, by *code*.

If I use the code like this, I can't choose the right value:

```
myDataSource_ds.linkType(JoinMode:: ...);
```

`JoinMode` only have the value ExistJoin - InnerJoin - NoExistJoin - Outerjoin , I can't set `Passive` or `Delayed`.

It's possible to have this values by code?

[image: DataSource property]

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong EDT. Use `FormLinkType::Passive` or `FormLinkType::Delayed`.